# jQuery replace dynamically added css in style-tag

Tags: jquery

Im adding css to the style-tag like so:

```
$("<style>").text(".out { background-color:#" + color + " !important; }").appendTo("head");
```

Is it possible to replace the contents of `.out` without creating a new definition each time?

Comment: Cant use `.css()` it wont apply to dynamically added elements added after the style was applied :/

Comment: It's usually best not to define css classes inside JS. Usually you just use `.addClass()` and add already defined classes to elements.

Comment: The contents of the class are colors, which I want to be changeable by the user so I cant predefine them as they could be any color :/

Comment: i don't think the browser will reload the css-definition, even if you found a working solution.. but i might be wrong.

Comment: So create a collection of classes to match your color options and change them with jQuery. If they're too many, create a single class and set the element style on elements with that class using jQuery. Your approach is needlessly cumbersome (and maybe impossible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best avoided except when it's necessary. Dynamic colors are a pretty good reason, though if you can just use the `.css()` method, that's preferable.

Anyway, here's how:

Select the style element by adding a class name to it:

```
<style class='current-color'>.out { background-color:#000 !important; }</style>
```

Then select it:

```
$('.current-color').text(".out { background-color:#" + color + " !important; }");
```

Little demo (not the same code): http://jsfiddle.net/p0tavns5/3/

To make it easier, store everything in an object with a `toCSS` method. Something like:

```
var class = { selector:'.out',
              attr:[ {background-color:'#000'},
                     {otherattr:'otherval'}]};
```

### Another way

You can also use dynamically created style sheets and [CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet.insertRule)

I'm not familiar with this way though.

Reading over that link, though, this doesn't look too hard.